# I can't seem to get these two buttons line up buttons like this. How can I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

**Design:**

[image]

**Explanation:**
So I used a div and added CSS (display: inline-block;) and width to it, they were perfectly fine, when I added a  tag into it to actually make the buttons do something they went on top of each other, I have tried wrapping them  tag in another div but can't seem to make it work.

**Here is how they look right now:**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
export default function About() {
    return (

        <div className="About--div">

            <h3 className="About--name">Huzaifa Aziz</h3>
            <h5 className="About--job">Frontend Developer</h5>
            <a className="About--site"></a>
            <div className="About--btn">
                <div>
                <form action="mailto:huzaifaaziz90@gmail.com">
                    <button className="Email--btn" ><i className='fa fa-envelope'></i> Email</button>
                </form>
                <div className="About--btn--space"></div>
                <form action="https://www.linkedin.com/in/huzaifah-aziz-63092996/">
                    <button className="Linkedin--btn"><i className='fa fa-linkedin'></i> Linkedin</button>
                </form>
                 </div>
                 </div>
        </div>
    )}
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
   
}
body{
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: #23252C;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #1A1B21;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

.About--div{
    text-align:center
    
    }

.About--name{
    color: white;
} 
   
.About--job{
    color: #F3BF99;

}

.About--site{
    color: #F5F5F5;

}
.About--btn{
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.About--btn--space{
    width: 17px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.Email--btn{
    background: whitesmoke;
    border: none;
    width: 115px;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 5px;
          
}

.Linkedin--btn{
    background: #5093E2;
    border: none;
    width: 115px;
    height: 34px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    
    
}

.fa fa-linkedin{
   
}
```

Comment: It is because your form elements are always going to display as block. You should not be using forms at all for this, but if you were going to you would use a single form element and have the actions tied to the button, not to the form. But there is no need to use a form with something like this. [Forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) are intended for submitting information from interactive controls. These are just simple links. Neither one of these should even technically be a button element, they should be `<a>`, but that is a semantics problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using flexbox, all you would need to do is add the following to the parent element of the buttons:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

Add a classname to that div just above your opening form tag and apply to that one. Other guys are right about the form tag being redundant but shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It is an issue in the sense that it is fundamentally wrong, is horrible semantically and for accessibility, and implies a misunderstanding of what these elements are for and how they should be used. Not correcting that, both for OP and for anyone else who comes here to read this question, is a mistake. Using flexbox also seems like overkill for this design. Nothing about it needs to flex, he just needs two links stylized as buttons of fixed width to sit next to each other with a little bit of margin between them.

Comment: @StephenMIrving He asked how to align them so I told him how and he clearly was ok with the result. The use of a form tag and buttons wouldn't be how I'd do it either but he didn't ask about that.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div className="about-buttons">
   <a className="about-button btn-email" href="mailto:huzaifaaziz90@gmail.com">
      <i className="fa fa-envelope"></i>Email
   </a>

   <a className="about-button btn-email" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/huzaifah-aziz-63092996/">
      <i className="fa fa-linkedin"></i>LinkedIn
   </a>
</div>
```

```css
.about-buttons {
   display: inline-block;
}

.about-button:not(:last-of-type) {
   margin-right: 25px;
}

.about-button i {
   margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: This is the actually correct answer. All other answers going along with OP like `<form>` and `<button>` elements are what he should be using here are fundamentally wrong. There is absolutely no reason he should ever use a form or button for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

A `<form>` by default uses `display: block`.

If you change this to e.g. **`display: inline-block`**, then they will flow one after the other, the same as regular text or like e.g. buttons do.

**Working demo:**

```js
// export default function About() {
// ...
// }

const About = function() {
  return (
    <div className="About--div">
      <h3 className="About--name">Huzaifa Aziz</h3>
      <h5 className="About--job">Frontend Developer</h5>
      <a className="About--site"></a>
      <div className="About--btn">
        <div>
          <form action="mailto:huzaifaaziz90@gmail.com">
            <button className="Email--btn" >
              <i className='fa fa-envelope'></i>
              Email
            </button>
          </form>
          <div className="About--btn--space"></div>
          <form action="https://www.linkedin.com/in/huzaifah-aziz-63092996/">
            <button className="Linkedin--btn">
              <i className='fa fa-linkedin'></i>
              Linkedin
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<About />, document.getElementById('react'));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
body{
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: #23252C;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #1A1B21;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
.About--div{
  text-align:center
}
.About--name{
  color: white;
} 
.About--job{
  color: #F3BF99;
}
.About--site{
  color: #F5F5F5;
}
.About--btn{
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.About--btn--space{
  width: 17px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.Email--btn{
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: none;
  width: 115px;
  height: 34px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.Linkedin--btn{
  background: #5093E2;
  border: none;
  width: 115px;
  height: 34px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.fa fa-linkedin{
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: He shouldn't be using forms or buttons at all for this though. The markup is all wrong. Trying to teach someone to cover for bad markup with CSS seems like a mistake.